# SQL Where Null Values

Tags: sql, null, where-clause, teradata

I have two tables which I need to use a where clause.
Table1

```
CustomerID     Product
1              Car
2              Table
3              Golf
4              Foo
5              Yoo
```

Table2

```
CustomeID      Comment
2              Three items
3              Returned
4              Complaint
```

I have a query which has two filters in the where statement like this

```
Select * from table1 a left
join table2 b on a.customerid= b.customerid
where b.comment<>'Returned' and b.comment not like 'Three%'
```

When I ran the query I just got one record. I want it to also return the two customerID's which are not in table2(three records)

Comment: So you are trying to filter out based on a `WHERE` condition but you also want to return the ones you're filtering out? What would your expected output be in a tabular format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a 
   LEFT JOIN table2 b on a.customerid= b.customerid 
WHERE (b.comment<>'Returned' and b.comment not like 'Three%') 
       OR (b.customerid is NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 A
LEFT JOIN Table2 B
ON A.CustomerID=B.CustomeID      
WHERE ( B.COMMENT<>'RETURNED' AND B.COMMENT NOT LIKE 'THREE%')
OR B.CustomeID  IS NULL
```

This should work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use LEFT OUTER JOIN:

```
Select * from table1 a left outer join table2 b on a.customerid = b.customerid where b.comment<>'Returned' and b.comment not like 'Three%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually tend not to JOIN that much.

```
SELECT --It's a good practice to enumerate all rows you need, not just *.
   T1.CUSTOMERID,
   T1.PRODUCT
FROM 
   TABLE1 T1
WHERE
   T1.CUSTOMERID NOT IN (
      SELECT
         T2.CUSTOMERID
      FROM
         TABLE2 T2
      WHERE
         T2.COMMENT !='Returned' AND
         T2.COMMENT not like 'Three%')
```